# Is it possible create subfolder in lang/en folder?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have this structure in my lang folder:

**en**/back/filename.php  file contains:

```
return array (
    'test' => 'test value',
);
```

**es**/back/filename.php file contains:

```
return array (
);
```

`dd(Lang::has('back/filename.test', 'es'));` returns true !!!

`{{ Lang::get('back/filename.test', array(), 'es') }}` returns **en** value ("test value") !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel will use the **fallback locale** in any case. It doesn't matter if you explicitly specify the locale or not.

Let's have a look at the code.

#### `Illuminate\Translation\Translator`

```
public function get($key, array $replace = array(), $locale = null)
{
    list($namespace, $group, $item) = $this->parseKey($key);

    foreach ($this->parseLocale($locale) as $locale)

    // ...
```

So `parseLocale()` returns the locales that should be used...

```
protected function parseLocale($locale)
{
    if ( ! is_null($locale))
    {
        return array_filter(array($locale, $this->fallback));
    }

    return array_filter(array($this->locale, $this->fallback));
}
```

As you can see, even if the `$locale` is not null it will use `$this->fallback` as second choice.

And `Lang::has()` will call `get()` too, so the same applies.

Comment: What to do then for locale?